# Catch animationstart and animationend events with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

I am currently working on an Angular based application that uses several transitions/animations. Even though I managed to catch the events `animationstart` and `animationend` using jQuery, I have not been able to do it using Angular. I tried using the following syntax with no result:

```
$scope.$on('webkitAnimationStart', function(){
    console.log("animation start caught")
    });
```

Is there a way to do it? Maybe using ngAnimate?

Comment: I cant recreate your example, so... guesswork. It's not emitted by `$scope` so your approach wont work. Does `angular.element($window).on('animationstart'` work?